# Is it possible to draw a homomorphism between all groups of the same finite order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

For example, if I have $2$ groups of order $n$, then could I label their elements $1,2,...,n$ and $1,2,...,m$ and say that $\phi(n)=m$

Comment: In general no. Since $\phi(n)=m$ implies that the order of $m$ divides the order of $n$ (Consider $\phi(n^k)=m^k$), which is not necessarily true for arbitrary groups with the same cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

There exist a homomorphism between two any group (at least the trivial one), but you will not have a priori an isomorphism between two group of same cardinal. For example, $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ and $\mathfrak S_3$ has same cardinal but they are not isomorphe.

Comment: Is this true in the situation described by Hurjkyl?

Comment: Yes of course there is a bijection between the to two groups, but it won't be a group morphism.@ZacharyCarter

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $n$ is 2. We apply your procedure as follows:

- For the first group we label the identity as 1 and the other element as 2
- For the second group we label the identity as 2 and the other element as 1

Then $\phi$ is a well-defined function, but it's not a group homomorphism, since it doesn't map the identity to the identity.

Comment: Is there an example of a pair of groups where the identity element of the one is the non-identity in another, while the identity of the latter group is a non-identity of the former? I would have thought that each of those groups would be isomorphic to $S_2$ and thus isomorphic to eachother